# Test class for Invocable Method from Flow

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, invocable-method

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to work out how to write a test class that gets any coverage for this method, which takes values from a screenflow and returns a value back to the flow.

if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be hugely appreciative.

```java
public class FormAssemblyEncrypt {
    public class FlowInputs {
        @InvocableVariable public String urlOppId;
        @InvocableVariable public String url;
        @InvocableVariable public String key;
        @InvocableVariable public String OppId;
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<String> updateOpp (List<FlowInputs> request) {

        String data = request[0].urlOppId.remove('=');
        String key = request[0].key;
        String url = request[0].url + request[0].urlOppId;
        String OppId = request[0].OppId;
        
        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(data), Blob.valueOf(key));
        String sig = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac), 'UTF-8');
        String urlencoded = url + '&signature=' + sig;
        
       
        //instantiate a new list 
        List <String> returnURL = new List <String> ();
        //add that modified opp to the new list
        returnURL.add(urlencoded);
        //send the new list of just one opp back to the Flow
        return returnURL;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). See if this helps: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96131/how-to-write-a-test-class-for-an-invocablemethod | If not, come back, and [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358226/edit) your question to add your test class and test method code. It's OK if it fails, but since this site exists to *help* you, not do it for you, you need to post a good-faith effort at attempting it yourself. *(From the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help): "We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services.")*

Comment: The short version is that you test it like you test any other apex method. It may be used in a flow, but there's nothing stopping you from calling `FormAssemblyEncrypt.updateOpp()` anywhere else. You just need to pass in some `FormAssemblyEncrypt.FlowInputs` (which you can also instantiate without any issue), gather the results, and make some assertions.